# User authentication through wp_signon(); help needed

Tags: wordpress, authorization

I use form to send POST request to a page and to login user with `wp_signon()` in order to authenticate user to my wordpress installation as described in WP documentation:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $_POST["user-login"];
$creds['user_password'] = $_POST["user-password"];
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

After this little piece of code I'm checking if user was logged in:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "SUCCESS"; } else { echo "FAIL!"; }
```

But I got `FAIL!` all the time. Then after sniffing around I found this little trick:

```
wp_set_current_user( $user );
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "SUCCESS"; } else { echo "FAIL!"; }
```

I've got `SUCCESS` on this one but when I leave this page I got `FAIL` again and again.

Can anyone explain me how to login user with `wp_signon()` without logging her out after page is changed or reloaded or whatever.

---

I've got desirable result when I go to `/wp_admin` and login with WP's default login form. I can navigate through every page of my WP site remaining logged-in all the time. But when I try to do this outside the default form with `wp_signon();` I `FAIL!`.

Maybe I use it wrong? Guide me! PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I used the whole structure on my localhost server which for some reason didn't allow wordpress to work correctly. After I've uploaded the template into an external server I've got this working.

Sorry for bothering! It won't happen again ...

Comment: Hi @LoomyBear, I have the same issue, it's really weird, the script works if the site is in domain.com/folder. But it doesn't work when it's on domain.com.

Can you tell me what structure did you mean which caused this problem?